# mongodb cluster replicas having different load average

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

i am facing a very strange issue with mongodb (4.4.x) cluster having 2 replicas with 30 Core& 128 GB of Ram & total database size is 30 Gb around
my cluster having a average hit-rate around 100-200 r/s & they are perfectly diverting read traffic on both replicas still both replicas having load average diff is around 1-5 times to each other
5m   10m  15m
Replica1- 5.85 5.93 5.56
Replica2- 1.00 1.02 1.05

& sometime vice-versa as well

Guys,
does anyone else face this type of issues

i have tried to change instance type & a lot of type mongo tuning from OS level as well